# Replacing a text in all columns with another text in datatable R

Tags: r, data.table

Found solution for `dataframe` to replace a text in all columns with another text. But i could not use the same for `datatable`. Below is what i tried. But when changed `data.frame` to `data.table` it doesnt give the correct data.

```
DF<- data.frame(lapply(DT, function(x) {gsub("abc", "xyz", x)}))
```

I need to find and replace all occurances of `abc` with `xyz` in all columns of a `data.table` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a `data.table` and we want to change all the column values, then use the `data.table` methods.  Based on the OP's code, we are selecting all the columns (so no need to specify `.SDcols`), loop through the Subset of Data.table with `lapply`, replace the 'abc' with 'xyz' with `gsub` (assuming there are multiple instances of 'abc') and update the original column by assigning (`:=`) the output back to the original columns

```
attrdata2[, names(attrdata2) := lapply(.SD, function(x) gsub("abc", "xyz", x))]
```

Comment: Thanks!! it works.. Can i ask another question? What if i want to replace less than zero to null ?  `gsub(as.numeric(x)<0,null, x)`  doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @sjd Perhaps you meant `NULL`, but I think it would be better to change it to `NA` and for that `gsub` is not needed `attrdata2[, names(attrdata2) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x < 0, NA))]`  (assuming these are `numeric` columns).  Also, another approach is `for` loop with `set` i.e `for(j in seq_along(attrdata2)) {i1 = which(attrdata2[[j]] < 0); set(attrdata2, i = i1, j = j, value = NA_real_)}`